# Why gradle tasks doesn't run in proper order

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-task

I have java project with 2 subprojects. With structure like this

```
- project_root
  |- client
     |- src
     |- build.gradle
  |- server
     |- src
     |- build.gradle
  |- build.gradle
```

All I need is to create 'deploy' task in root buiild.gradle with next actions:

- clean all subprojects
- clean 'target' folder
- make jars for all subprojects
- copy jars from all subprojects to folder 'target' in root
- make an archive of the target folder.

This is how I try to do this

root build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task cleanTarget(type: Delete) {
    delete "target"
    delete "target.zip"
}

task cleanAll() {
    dependsOn cleanTarget
    dependsOn clean
    dependsOn subprojects.clean
}

task jarChilds() {
    dependsOn subprojects.jar
}

task copyFiles(type: Copy) {
    copy {
        from("client/build/libs/")
        into project.file('target')
    }
    copy {
        from("server/build/libs/")
        into project.file('target')
    }
}

task zipApp(type: Zip) {
    from 'target/'
    include '*'
    include '*/*'
    archiveName 'target.zip'
    destinationDir(project.rootDir)
}

task deploy{
    dependsOn cleanAll
    dependsOn jarChilds
    dependsOn copyFiles
    dependsOn zipApp
    jarChilds.shouldRunAfter cleanAll
    copyFiles.shouldRunAfter jarChilds
    zipApp.shouldRunAfter copyFiles
}
```

Every task runs properly if I manually run it, but if I run 'deploy'  folder 'target' didn't create. Here is log output:

```
Executing task 'deploy'...

> Task :clean
> Task :cleanTarget
> Task :client:clean
> Task :server:clean
> Task :cleanAll
> Task :client:compileKotlin
> Task :client:compileJava
> Task :client:processResources
> Task :client:classes
> Task :client:inspectClassesForKotlinIC

> Task :client:jar
Client jar done

> Task :server:compileKotlin
> Task :server:compileJava
> Task :server:processResources
> Task :server:classes
> Task :server:inspectClassesForKotlinIC

> Task :server:jar
Server jar done

> Task :jarChilds
> Task :copyFiles NO-SOURCE
> Task :zipApp NO-SOURCE
> Task :deploy


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3s
14 actionable tasks: 14 executed
12:39:15: Task execution finished 'deploy'.
```

I see that error "NO-SOURCE", but folders 'client/build/libs' and 'server/build/libs' exist and contain jars. I can be sure because the manual running task 'copyFiles' create folder 'target' and copy all files.
The only possible option that I see is 'copyFiles' task running before 'jarChilds'. But I don't understand why. What am I missing, why is it not working?

P/S/ Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your task `copyFiles` uses the method [`copy`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#copy-groovy.lang.Closure-) of the [`Project`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html) instance instead of configuring the actual task. This is the reason why the task stays unconfigured and, once it is executed, reports that there are no files to process (`NO-SOURCE`). To configure your task, use methods of the task type [`Copy`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html):

```
task copyFiles(type: Copy) {
    from("client/build/libs/")
    from("server/build/libs/")
    into("target")
}
```

---

Additional hint: You probably do not need your task `copyFiles` at all. Instead, you may just use the task `zipApp` to collect the files:

```
task zipApp(type: Zip) {
    from subprojects.jar
    archiveName 'target.zip'
    destinationDir(project.rootDir)
}
```

By putting the `jar` tasks of the `subprojects` into the `from` method, Gradle will even add the task dependencies automatically, so you won't need to register them using `dependsOn`.

Check out the following short and complete `build.gradle` file:

```
subprojects {                    // using subprojects here, because your root project has no sources
    apply plugin: 'java'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {       // without the 'java' plugin, there is no automatic 'clean' task
    dependsOn subprojects.clean
    delete 'target.zip'
}

task zipApp(type: Zip) {
    mustRunAfter clean
    from subprojects.jar
    archiveName 'target.zip'
    destinationDir(project.rootDir)
}

task deploy {
    dependsOn clean
    dependsOn zipApp
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! You saved my time, I already spent all day on it.